# Create Root Category in magento programatically

Tags: category, programmatically

I want to create a Root Category programatically, i am using this function but category is created under magento "Default Category".

[<strike>example</strike>](http://www.helpcheer.com/add-category-programmatically-magento-custom-field/)

Comment: I  have put reopen vote for this question. I Guss that it have enough info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever,you want to create a root category then must set

- `Store id as 0`
- `Parent id(parent)  set  as  1.`

### Code:

```
$storeId    = 0;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setStoreId($storeId);
$category->setName('Test category');
$category->setUrlKey('Test category');
$category->setIsActive(1);
$category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
$parentId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
$category->save();
```

Comment: Working correctly....

Answer (score 1):

If you set correct parent category ID, it should work. Try category ID 1 for parent category ID.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require "app/Mage.php";

umask(0);

Mage::app('admin');

try{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $category->setName('Test category');
    $category->setUrlKey('Test category');
    $category->setIsActive(1);
    $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
    $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1); // this is where you set parent category id
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
    $category->save();
} catch(Exception $e) {
  // log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work I guess

```
/**
 * creates a new category for store-ID with the data of the template category.
 *
 * @param int    $template ID of the category to clone from
 * @param string $name     of the category to add
 *
 * @return int ID of the newly created category
 *
 * @throws RuntimeException
 */
protected function _addRootCategory($template, $name)
{
    $storeId = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;

    /** @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($template);
    if (!$category->getId()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Failed to load template category by id %d', $template));
    }

    $category = clone $category;
    $category->setId(null);
    $category->setData('name', $name);
    $category->setData('url_key', $name . '-catalog');
    $category->setData('display_mode', 'PRODUCTS');
    $category->setData('level', 1);
    $category->setData('store', $storeId);
    $category->getResource()->save($category);
    $categoryId = $category->getId();
    if (!$categoryId) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            sprintf('Failed to create new root category "%s" for store ID %d', $name, $storeId)
        );
    }

    $parentId = 1;
    $category->move($parentId, null);

    return $categoryId;
}
```